# How to do a "color-by-number" plot in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I have two parameters or coordinates x and y, and a quantity E(x,y,p) which is a function of those two parameters, but also depends on a state matrix p. I have a few discrete options for the state p - say, p1, p2, p3... - and for every pair (x,y) I run some calculations to find which of the possible states p minimizes E(x,y,p).

Once I have this information, I would like to make a 2D plot in which the region surrounding the point (x,y) is colored e.g. green if state p1 minimized E, blue if state p2 minimized E, etc.

There's probably a simple way to do this that I just haven't figured out yet. I didn't see a good way to do it among the specialized plots, but I was having trouble understanding a few that may have been relevant, e.g. pcolor and patch. Any advice on how to do this?

The best I've thought of is using surf with the z-value used to control the color, and then doing a top-down view of the 3D plot to get the 2D plot I want. That seems like a clunky way of doing things, though.

Comment: Please provide the codes of the attempts you already tried, and maybe a drawing(?) of what you want to achieve in the end. I guess, that'd help others to better understand what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! In the end, I was able to figure it out. The initial example I was reading from in the documentation was more complicated than I had needed, but trying from the simplest possible case (as I explain in the answer I just posted) I was able to get it to work to the degree I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the job with pcolor after all. I defined `Emin(x,y)=E(x,y,p)` for the `p` that minimized `E(x,y,p)` and then called `pcolor(Emin)`. I was able to add ticks on the axes by calling `pcolor(xvec,yvec,Emin)` where `xvec` is an array of the different values of `x` used, etc.

`pcolor` works by coloring in cells based on the vertices defined by `xvec` and `yvec`, or if those are not given, based on the indices of `Emin`, this doesn't center the cells on the coordinates corresponding to that value. For example, if I calculate `Emin(1,2)=5` and call `pcolor(Emin)` then the cell with the color corresponding to 5 will have its corner at coordinates (1,2). I can fix this by shifting `xvec` and `yvec` by half the width of a cell. For cells of unit width, for example, this would be `xvec = xvec - 0.5`. The last row and column of `Emin` don't show up, but I can fix this by adding a dummy row and column to it.

In case it's relevant, I was only using linearly spaced `xvec` and `yvec`, so if there could be complications I avoided with other spacings.

Hopefully this makes some sense to anyone else who has trouble reading the documentation for `pcolor` that I had found.